# Filter range from two dates in the same query Django/Python

Tags: python, django, datetime, model

I need the result from a query that filters two dates from the same model. I need to get in the result 5 days (today plus 4 days) from original date and sale from target date (today plus 4 more days) both in the same query.

This is my code:

```
    startdate = datetime.now().date()
    endate = datetime.now().date() + timedelta(days=4)
    lineas_de_reporte = Reporteots.objects.filter(original_fcd_date__range=[startdate, endate], target_pdate__range=[startdate, endate])
```

But I'm not getting the result I want, any idea?

Comment: It is not clear what kind of result you expect. Also, the code of your model will help

Comment: let me edit my question

Comment: There it is I tried to be more clear, let me know if you need more data

Comment: First, the `datetime` module has `datetime.date.today()` which should be helpful.  `__range` translates to a sql `between` query which is a half open interval (i.e. it includes the lower bound, but not the upper bound -- `startdate <= value < endate`)

Answer (score 0):

In your code, don't use bracket with __range.

```
  startdate = datetime.date().today()
  endate = datetime.date().today() + timedelta(days=4)
  lineas_de_reporte = Reporteots.objects.filter(original_fcd_date__range=(startdate, endate), target_pdate__range=(startdate, endate))
```

Comment: Hi Wilfried, I notice that yesterday. But still not getting the full data

Comment: Can you show me data in your database ? And the models

Comment: Your second are very long ;)