# Create a string that contains values from related objects to display in view

Tags: django

I'm new to Django so please bear with me. I'm trying to create a view which lists JournalEntries which have type=BP. The list needs to include selected values from the LineItems that are related to each JournalEntry. Each JournalEntry with type=BP only ever has two related LineItems.

models.py

```
class JournalEntry(models.Model):
    date = models.DateField(null=True, blank=False)
    TYPE = (
        ('BP', 'Bank Payment'),
        ('YE', 'Year End'),
    )
    type = models.CharField(
        max_length=2,
        choices=TYPE,
        blank=True,
        default='0'
        )

class LineItem(models.Model):
    journal_entry = models.ForeignKey(JournalEntry, on_delete=models.PROTECT)
    ledger = models.ForeignKey(Ledger, on_delete=models.PROTECT)
    description = models.CharField(max_length=255, null=True, blank=True)
    cr = models.DecimalField(max_digits=8, decimal_places=2, null=True, blank=True)
    dr = models.DecimalField(max_digits=8, decimal_places=2, null=True, blank=True)

class Ledger(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
```

views.py

```
def journalentries_show_all(request):
    journal_entries = JournalEntry.objects.filter(type="BP")

    context = {
        'journal_entries': journal_entries,
    }
    return render(request, 'journal/journalentries_show_all.html', context)
```

My template journalentries_show_all.html

```
<ul>
 {% for journal_entry in journal_entries %}
  <li>{{ journal_entry.date }}</li>
  <li>{{ ledger name from first line item in this journal_entry }}</li>
  <li>{{ ledger name from second line item in this journal_entry }}</li>
  <li>{{ description from first line item in this journal_entry }}</li>
  <li>{{ description from second line item in this journal_entry }}</li>
 {% endfor %}
</ul>
```

In this particular view I'm only interested in displaying JournalEntries which has type=BP, all of which only ever have two line items. Other types of JournalEntries have more LineItems, but those are dealt with in another view.

Answer (score 0):

Basic Python iteration is enough for what your need

```
results = []
for entry in journal_entries:
    results.append(entry.lineitem_set.all()[2]
```

Just that `results` list should do it in the `context`. `.all()[2]` will send a query with a limit for the first 2 items. You will get the whole items. Select what you need to display in the template, not the views.
To make your life easier, you can also define a `related_name` attribute on foreign keys and use the name you want there instead of the generated `*_set`

Comment: Thank you, but won't this create a list composed of the first LineItems of each JournalEntry. The list will then have no relation to the JournalEntries.

In my view I want to display a list like this:
<JournalEntry.id> <JournalEntry.date> <Ledger name from this JournalEntries first Lineitem> <Ledger name from JournalEntries second Lineitem> <Description from this Journal Entry's first LineItem> <Description from this Journal Entry's second lineitem>

Answer (score 0):

Why do you want to pass the information as a string? It's an extra step that doesn't add anything. You can pass in entire dictionaries as the `context` variable so that's what I'd recommend you do. In your view, it is possible to request rows based off of a filter as seen in the docs [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/db/queries/#retrieving-specific-objects-with-filters). Then you can pass the data from the query into the template as a dictionary.

Also why does your `JournalEntry` model only have one field? Can we just combine the `JournalEntry` and `LineItem` into something like this:

```py
class LineItem(models.Model):
    date = models.DateField(null=True, blank=False)
    # journal_entry = models.ForeignKey(JournalEntry, on_delete=models.PROTECT)
    # this journal_entry fk wouldn't work so you'd have to replace it with something else
    ledger = models.ForeignKey(Ledger, on_delete=models.PROTECT)
    description = models.CharField(max_length=255, null=True, blank=True)
    cr = models.DecimalField(max_digits=8, decimal_places=2, null=True, blank=True)
    dr = models.DecimalField(max_digits=8, decimal_places=2, null=True, blank=True)
```

Then for the view I would write something like this:

views.py

```py
from .models import LineItem

def journalentries_show_all(request):
    context = LineItem.objects.filter(arbitrary_criteria = True) # choose your own criteria here

    return render(request, 'journal/journalentries_show_all.html', context)
```

The important part would be choosing the filter. If you want to do the first two by date you can follow the example [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41770797/filter-range-from-two-dates-in-the-same-query-django-python).

Comment: Agreed, it doesn't seem to make much sense to separate the date and the actual data.

Comment: The JournalEntry model has extra info which I removed here to keep things simple. Some types of JournalEntries will also have many more related LineItems, but those will be dealt with in different views.

I know I can pass entire dictionaries to my template, I just don't know how to then access the LineItem data when displaying a JournalEntry. Eg in my template, I want to list my Journal entries alongside from data from their LineItems as follows:

<JournalEntry.id><JournalEntry.date><Ledger name from this JournalEntries first Lineitem> <Ledger name from JournalEntries second Lineitem> etc

Comment: Oh yeah that makes sense. In that case you can make queries to the line item object using the journal entry as a filter.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe I understood you wrong but why don't you just send your JournalEntry querset to your template?

```
def journalentries_show_all(request):
    context['journal_entries'] = JournalEntry.objects.all()
    ....
```

Then you can display what you want in your template

```
{% for entry in journal_entries %}
{{ entry.id }} {{ entry.date }}
{% for item in entry.lineitem_set.all|slice:"2" %}
{{ item.ledger.name }}
{% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
```

Answer (score 0):

After some digging I found that I can access related variables direct in the template as follows:

```
<td>{{ journal_entry.date }}</td>
<td>{{ journal_entry.lineitem_set.all.1.ledger }}</td>
<td>{{ journal_entry.lineitem_set.all.0.ledger }}</td>
<td>{{ journal_entry.lineitem_set.all.1.description|truncatechars:15 }}</td>
<td>{{ journal_entry.lineitem_set.all.0.description|truncatechars:15 }}</td>
```